# How to convert d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss to yyyyMMdd in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to convert **d/m/yyyy** or **dd/m/yyyy** or **d/mm/yyyy** to **yyyyMMdd** format in Excel. The original value looks like **3/3/2014 8:00:00 am**.

If all dates would be same length I could do left, mid, and so on to reverse the date and truncate the time. But how can I do this when I have dates with three different lengths?

This works with fixed length: `=DATE(MID(A1;7;4); LEFT(A1;2); MID(A1;4;2))`

Comment: Use `FIND`, to find the position of `/`, then use your formula.

Comment: Can't you just format the cell itself?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, maybe that was the first thing I tried?

Comment: @BakedInhalf - how are we supposed to know?  You never mentioned that you tried it.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I assumed you did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

=TEXT(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)),"yyyymmdd")

[image]

**NOTE:**

The month and day in the input must be in the correct order for the *DATEVALUE()* function.

For data like:

25/12/2014 8:00:00 am

I would use the following *UDF*

```
Public Function INeedADate(s As String) As Date
    ary = Split(Trim(s), " ")
    bry = Split(Trim(ary(0)), "/")
    INeedADate = DateSerial(bry(2), bry(1), bry(0))
End Function
```

[image]

In this case the cell **B1** must be formatted *Custom* **>** *"yyyymmdd"*

Comment: Strange, I get #VALUE!

Comment: From the **formula** or from the **UDF??**